# Katalon Studio + JIRA cloud integration

Tags: katalon-studio

I am trying to integrate JIRA cloud with Katalon Studio.

On clicking `Add New issue` it is not opening the create issue native submission form. But on clicking `link existing issue` it is linking.

Can anyone please help?